# AXIS2Server packed with ESB 4.9.0 doesn't start while it works fine 4.8.0

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, wso2-esb

AXIS2Server packed with ESB 4.9.0 doesn't start while it works fine 4.8.0.. .any help

Hi, I'm running ESB 4.9.0 on Win 7 OS 64-it. 
Let's say my esb is available at following location
D:\wso2esb\samples\axis2Server
As per instructions to run samples, I'm able to successfully build sample apps using ant but axis2 server doesn't start at all. It prints following on CMD when i execute axis2server.bat. Am i missing something?

=========================================================

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\kashif.kazi>d:

D:\>cd wso2esb\samples\axis2Server\

D:\wso2esb\samples\axis2Server>axis2server.bat
"Starting Sample Axis2 Server ..."
Using AXIS2_HOME:        D:\wso2esb\samples\AXIS2S~1\
Using JAVA_HOME:       C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server       to select the "server" VM
    -hotspot      is a synonym for the "server" VM  [deprecated]
                  The default VM is server.

    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions with specified granularity
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions with specified granularity
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                  see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument

    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for m
ore details.
D:\wso2esb\samples\axis2Server>
```

=========================================================

Answer (score 13):

you can use the .bat or .sh from old WSO2 ESB 4.8.0 or fix the issue: 
Just need to open the .bat or .sh with a text editor and find the line with this string(for windows SO):

```
-Djava.io.tmpdir="%AXIS2_HOME%..\..\tmp\"
```

try to remove the \ after tmp and run your server again and this is all.

Comment: great!! please set my answer as the rigth ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Correct the axis2server.bat script as shown below:

On line 126 make the following amendments:

1. Remove the trailing '\' after tmp at the end of the *java.io.tmpdir* declaration: i.e change `-Djava.io.tmpdir="%AXIS2_HOME%..\..\tmp\" %_SERVERNAME%` to `-Djava.io.tmpdir="%AXIS2_HOME%..\..\tmp" %_SERVERNAME%`
2. Add a (missing) '\' in the *conf* declaration before 'repository': i.e. change `-conf "%AXIS2_HOME%repository\conf\axis2.xml"` to `-conf "%AXIS2_HOME%\repository\conf\axis2.xml"`

Save and re-run the `axis2server.bat` script.

Comment: I had similar issue, and this above solution worked for me as well. +1