# Currently i am using WSO2ESB 4.9.0 Version i am unable run the samples Axis2server.bat file

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Problem in running Samples of WSO2ESB Axis2server.bat
Iam getting below result

```
C:\wso2esb-4.9.0\samples\axis2Server>axis2server.bat
"Starting Sample Axis2 Server ..."
Using AXIS2_HOME:        C:\WSO2ES~1.0\samples\AXIS2S~1\
Using JAVA_HOME:       C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server       to select the "server" VM
    -hotspot      is a synonym for the "server" VM  [deprecated]
                  The default VM is server.

    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions with specified granularity
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions with specified granularity
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                  see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
```

"it is giving me the instructions of command usage...but it is not executing the wrapper.jar file."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wso2 samples not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36855126/wso2-samples-not-working)

Comment: Wait bro i will check...

Comment: Hai its not working i have changed the \\ and without slash ....

Comment: as per your instructions i tried to edit axis2server.bat but -XX:MaxPermSize=256m already there in the bat file...

Comment: Actually i am following a youtube vedio "WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus Quick Start Guide Part 1"

Comment: In that vedio he is getting execution resultn in cmd prmpt like Wrapper started as console... Launching a JVM ...Wrapper version<3.2.3>.......Notice here he is getting wrapper class executed but here in my cmd iam not getting wrapper class execution..i don't know why it is not getting executed.....in my dump iam unable to find wrapper .jar file ..but i have downloaded seperatly and kept in the bin foledr..still its not working....can u please help me out this.

Comment: Could you try by setting -Djava.io.tmpdir to "C:\tmp" for the line starting from "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" .  So the full line is "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java"  -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m  -classpath "%SAMPLE_SERVERPATH%" -Djava.io.tmpdir="C:\tmp" %_SERVERNAME% %_HTTPPORT% %_HTTPSPORT% %_XDEBUG% -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%AXIS2_ENDORSED%"  -Djar.class.paths=%CARBON_CLASSPATH% -Dsystem.home="."  samples.util.Bootstrap  -repo "%AXIS2_HOME%\repository" -conf "%AXIS2_HOME%repository\conf\axis2.xml"

Comment: @Harishbabu, Have you removed the `MaxPermSize` flag from startup script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AXIS2Server packed with ESB 4.9.0 doesn't start while it works fine 4.8.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32866263/axis2server-packed-with-esb-4-9-0-doesnt-start-while-it-works-fine-4-8-0)

Comment: Hai abimaran i have successfully started axis2server.bat by removing \ after the temp ....

Comment: Now i am got another issue that is when i am opening the Management console window the URL https://localhost:9443/carbon iam getting below Error.....Error 404: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.exception.NoTargetForURIException: No target servlet configured for uri: /carbon

Comment: Hai abimaran When i am runing the client axis2client in cmd prompt i am not getting the stock price . iam getting the below result in cmd.Jars are deployed successfully and its continues...with below java error..

Comment: [java] [2016-04-28 01:22:32,845] ERROR {org.apache.sandesha2.SandeshaModule} -  Could not load module policies. Using default values.
     [

Comment: java] [2016-04-28 01:22:33,024]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportSender} -  MAILTO Sender started
     [java] [2016-04-28 01:22:33,044]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender} -  JMS Sender started
     [java] [2016-04-28 01:22:33,044]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender} -  JMS Transport Sender initialized...

Comment: [java] [2016-04-28 01:22:33,129] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils} -  Address information does not exist in the Endpoint Reference (EPR).The system ca
nnot infer the transport mechanism.org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Address information does not exist in the Endpoint Reference (EPR).The system cannot infer the transport me
chanism.
     [java]
     [java]     at org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils.inferOutTransport(ClientUtils.java:73)

Comment: [java]     at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.prepareMessageContext(OperationClient.java:288)
     [java]     at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:176)
     [java]     at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)

Comment: [java]     at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:554)
     [java]     at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:530)
     [java]     at samples.userguide.StockQuoteClient.executeClient(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at samples.userguide.StockQuoteClient.main(Unknown Source)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 10 seconds

Comment: Sorry abhiraman iam unable to paste the whole think that's why i need paste it in multiple parts please see the below issue....combine the whole part in the notepad and see it.........copy from the top to bottom....

Comment: thats the issue ......please help me out this..

Answer (score 1):

In line 115 the original file have:

```
"set CARBON_CLASSPATH=..\..\repository\axis2\client\lib\bcprov-jdk15on.jar,%CARBON_CLASSPATH%"
```

You need to modify that line to use bcprov-jdk15.jar instead of bcprov-jdk15on.jar.

In line 126 the original file have:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java"  -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m  -classpath "%SAMPLE_SERVERPATH%" -Djava.io.tmpdir="%AXIS2_HOME%..\..\tmp\" %_SERVERNAME% %_HTTPPORT% %_HTTPSPORT% %_XDEBUG% -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%AXIS2_ENDORSED%"  -Djar.class.paths=%CARBON_CLASSPATH% -Dsystem.home="."  samples.util.Bootstrap  -repo "%AXIS2_HOME%\repository" -conf "%AXIS2_HOME%repository\conf\axis2.xml
```

Please replace with with this line:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java"  -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m  -classpath "%SAMPLE_SERVERPATH%" -Djava.io.tmpdir="%AXIS2_HOME%..\..\tmp\sampleServer" %_SERVERNAME% %_HTTPPORT% %_HTTPSPORT% %_XDEBUG% -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%AXIS2_ENDORSED%"  -Djar.class.paths=%CARBON_CLASSPATH% -Dsystem.home="."  samples.util.Bootstrap  -repo "%AXIS2_HOME%\repository" -conf "%AXIS2_HOME%repository\conf\axis2.xml
```